# Can't open Activity in options menu

Tags: android, eclipse, android-optionsmenu

I have options menu that opens successfully with icon, but, when I click on it, it does nothing, and also there is nothing in neither LogCat nor error log. Here is my main activity and email activty. I have all buttons in `email.xml` and one item in `gameoptions.xml`. Please help.

```
private ListView lv1; 

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.gameoptions, menu);
    menu.findItem(R.id.btn_market);
    return true;}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.btn_market:
            startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(),EmailActivity.class));
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

email activity:

```
public class EmailActivity extends Activity {
    Button send;
    EditText address, subject, emailtext;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE); 
        setContentView(R.layout.email);

        Button b=(Button)this.findViewById(R.id.btn_market);
        b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
            public void onClick(View arg0){ 
                Uri address=Uri.parse("https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=ru.kenzhekul.tashiev&hl=ru");
                Intent surf=new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, address);
                startActivity(surf);
            }
        }); 

        send = (Button) findViewById(R.id.emailsendbutton);
        address = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.emailaddress);
        //subject = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.emailsubject);
        emailtext = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.emailtext);

        send.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                final Intent emailIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                emailIntent.setType("plain/text");
                emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL,new String[] { address.getText().toString() });
                emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,emailtext.getText().toString());
                EmailActivity.this.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Отправка письма"));
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The line `startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(),EmailActivity.class));` is wrong.

You cannot start an activity with application context as you wrote. You should pass an activity instance instead of the application context.

EDIT: If you are in a class of an activity, try pass `this` instead.

Comment: Add log before starting the activity (from the menu) and check if this call is called at all. If not, probably a problem in your menu. If it is called and still not working so you probably have an exception or something in your logs.

Answer (score 1):

you should pass `this` not `getApplicationContext()`!

Answer (score 0):

In your method **onOptionsItemSelected** try removing switch statement and simply put Log there I guess issue is with button ID.